# jQuery css method not working in Wordpress Theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a jQuery function

```
$('.container').css('marginRight');
```

It returns the proper values in Chrome, Safari and Firefox however in IE and Edge I get a error saying "Object doesn't support property or method 'css'

If it helps i'm using the Understrap starter theme.

Comment: Make sure that your $('.container') is a jQuery Object. Or your element with class 'container' is defined after the jQuery script.

Comment: @MikeC, you have to pass value also,(i.e) >>$('.container').css('margin-right','20px');

Comment: @Samyappa - OP don't want to set the `margin-right`, instead want to get its value.